# After update android studio could not create parent directory for lock file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Updated android studio and plugins when sync, fails with could not create parent directory for lock file

wrapper properties:

```
#Sun Mar 05 16:51:59 PKT 2017 distributionBase=
GRADLE_USER_HOME  distributionPath=wrapper/
dists  zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME zipStorePath=wrapper/
dists  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/
gradle- 3.3-all.zip
```

build.gradle app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.sarahn.toyapplication"
minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 25
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-   rules.pro'
}
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:
2.2.2',   {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

build.gradle(project)

```
`// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
common to  all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
jcenter()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
}

}

allprojects {
repositories {
jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

tried downloading NDK, deleting .gradle folder from project and from installs but not going forward

Environment:
Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to that location where gradle build failed to create parent directory and deleted cache folder there

Comment: any other way to do this?

Comment: Could you question and give link here

Comment: And why tou dnt want to delete cache folder?

Comment: Did you invalide cache restart?

Comment: This problem is only coming in windows.

Comment: Its for Windows, find the path where its telling you not locate and delete folder

Comment: did that, deleted all the files inside .gradle...still it's not workin

Comment: you had to delete cache folder

Comment: Not worked for me, with andNot worked for me, with android studio v3.4.1.roid studio v3.4.1.

Answer (score 15):

Verify the Gradle User Home path in the Android studio:

File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Keep the Gradle User Home Empty.

[image: Image for Settings in Android Studio]

Comment: Only this worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

In case someone has the same issue with Intellij on Ubuntu, the following solved my issue:

Remove everything in `~/.gradle/caches`

Answer (score 0):

Just go to gradle folder inside your android studio path and change the version of your gradle,  by dowloading the latest gradle version.
then go to android studio > settings and change gradle version to the one that you installed

Answer (score 0):

For my case, (Win 10 64bits and Android Studio 3.1.3 I had to run the Android Studio as Administrator in order to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me android studio version `3.3.1`

Click on `File` in the app bar then `Invalidate caches / Restart`  then `INVALIDATE AND RESTART`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me Android Studio v3.0

delete in the root folder .gradlew gradle.bat(on windows) , gradle/ .idea/
reopen the project.

Comment: no, these files are within the project root folder. :)