# Error:Could not create parent directory for lock file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sdk

Whenever I try to build a new project then this error occurs

```
Error:Could not create parent directory for lock file
```

Gradle version 3.3

Android plugin version 2.3.3

This is my build.gradle

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823697/after-update-android-studio-could-not-create-parent-directory-for-lock-file

Comment: where to able to correct this error?