# Not able to create parent directory for lock file

Tags: android, gradle-plugin

Error : Could not create parent directory for lock file.

I have the following error everytime when i try to create a new project. I found some solutions over internet but they are not enough to solve my problem.

I had already tried deleting of cache in gradle but that does not work.Plz help me!

Error:

```
Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3-all.zip.lck
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After update android studio could not create parent directory for lock file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823697/after-update-android-studio-could-not-create-parent-directory-for-lock-file)

Comment: @billynomates , thanks but I had already gone through that solution.

Comment: You should say what you've already tried in your post

Comment: I had cleared the cache folder already, removed gradle folder in user directory, also did invalidate cache\.restart.  Now I am searching for that solution which could solve my problem.

Comment: any headway guys?