# deleted .gradle directory, now project can't refresh

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I'm working in the Intellij IDEA, and I'm having trouble assessing this problem with gradle. I reached a school lab machine memory quota, so I was told to delete my .gradle directory given that was taking up the most space. But now i can't seem to refresh my gradle build at all.

Some time has passed since I deleted the .gradle/ directory. I checked just now and found that I could enter the directory via terminal (linux), but running "ls" doesn't display any contents of the folder.

Attempting to refresh within intellij gets me the following error message:

Error: Could not create parent directory for lock file ~/.gradle/wrapper/distsgadlle-3.5-rc-2-bin/7ktl4k9rdug30mawecgppf5ms/gradle-3.5-rc-2-bin.zip.lck

I looked up this error and I find the following stackoverflow question to be commonly cited

[After update android studio could not create parent directory for lock file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823697/after-update-android-studio-could-not-create-parent-directory-for-lock-file)

Which encourages the user to go to the file location where the gradle build failed and delete a cache folder. If that file location is supposed to be .gradle/wrapper/... well, I've already ran into a big issue. I can't cd into .gradle/wrapper from terminal, and it doesn't appear when I run "ls" in the ./gradle folder. It may not exist.

Comment: Usually the cache is at: /Users/<You>/AppData/Local/Gradle/ something else I dont remember, the other one is the folder generated and build from within the project folder

Comment: Did you try building your project form command line instead of IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your file explorer
2. Go inside the `.gradle` directory
3. Inside the `.gradle` directory, there will be a subdirectory named `caches`
4. Delete the `caches` folder
5. Sync your Android project